# Integral form of Nørlund Polynomial

Tags: integration, polynomials, bernoulli-numbers

Nørlund Polynomials $B_n^s(0) $ are defined as $B_n^s(0)=   \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac {d^n}{dt^n} \left ( \frac {t}{e^t-1} \right) ^s$

For $s=1$, $B_n^s(0)= 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {(-\frac {1}{2}+it)  ^n}{(e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t})^2}dt   $

Is there some integral representation of Nørlund Polynomials for any $s $? It is important for me to save form $B_n^s(0)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (-\frac {1}{2}+it)  ^n ×f (s)dt   $

Comment: Have you seen this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122106001064) ?

Comment: Yes, and nothing helpful in my problem. I've seen something like 10 article about Nørlund Polynomials and unfortunatelly did't find anything. I teoretycly have an anwser but not satisfying.

Comment: Try taking the $n$th derivative of the definite integral representation of $\left(\frac t{e^t-1}\right)^s$ or find an integral representation of  these [Stirling number representations](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/NorlundB2/27/01/)